# How to implement Hierarchy of Roles/designations in an organization & transact between them in JAVA

Tags: java, transactions, view, roles

I know Java & currently I’m learning Spring (have learnt Core part till now).
I want to implement a Diary System where details of the diary or letter or file is noted with each passing node, for better accountability & transparency.
But my problem is that I’ve to also create hierarchy of users, each having different roles/ranks. Let’s say there are Divisions then each Division having different Section under them, each having different quantity of employees working under them. Employees will also be transferred to different Sections/Divisions, thus roles & duties will be changed accordingly by the Admin.
I have created simple login system. But assigning roles to different employees & then providing tasks to them according to their roles/ranks, besides creating hierarchical pyramid of employees working in an office is something which seems difficult for me.
Can someone guide me soon please?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have you seen the spring-security (oauth2) example for that

Comment: You could have a class called ``Roles`` annotate it as ``Entity``. Now add the ``Roles`` class in your entity classes and map it as ``@OneToOne``. Now during persistence, you can set to the particular user the role you want. Regarding tasks, you could retrieve all the users and check their roles and have a method that assigns a certain method to a certain role.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) helps you to understand more about users and their roles in management,

apart from that creating a hierarchical pyramid of employees working in an office is something that you should create own according to your business logic.